# Batch File Help to change a text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a huge list of emails - around 8,000.

They are curently in a long list format.

eg.

```
someone@website.com
someone2@website.com
```

The email sending program requires them to be in the format below.

```
Company
E-mail: someone@website.com

Company
E-mail: someone2@website.com
```

It needs to have company, then email:, then a blank line, before going onto the next line.

Can anyone help with a batch file.

Comment: At which point your code fails? You should show us your code.

Comment: -1: You need to show what you've tried. Stack Overflow isn't a "code this for me" website.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (textfile.txt) do (
echo Company
echo Email: %%a
echo.
) >>temp.txt
del textfile.txt /f /q
ren temp.txt textfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo OFF

For /F "Tokens=*" %%# in ('Type "File.txt"') Do (
    (
      Echo Company
      Echo E-mail: %%#
      Echo+
    ) >> ".\Output.txt"
)

Pause&Exit
```